# Prevent Form Resubmission on Page Refresh - Django

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I encountered an issue in my Django project where refreshing the page after a form submission would trigger a resubmission of the form, causing unexpected behavior. I found a workaround that involves redirecting to a success page and then back to the original form page.

Step 1: Create a Success Page (success_page.html)

html

Copy code

```
<title>Success Page</title>

{% load static %}
```

```
<script>

    window.location.href = '{% url "your_page_with_form_url_name_in_urls.py" %}';

</script>
```

Step 2: Modify Your Django View

In your Django view (views.py), modify it to redirect to the success page on form submission:

python

Copy code

## views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def your_view(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    # Your logic for handling form submission

    return render(request, 'success_page.html')



# Render your form page for normal requests

return render(request, 'your_page_with_form.html', context)
```

Explanation:

Success Page: The success_page.html contains a simple JavaScript script to redirect to your form page using window.location.href.

Django View: In your Django view, when the form is submitted (POST request), it renders the success_page.html. For normal requests, it renders your form page (your_page_with_form.html) along with the desired context.

This approach avoids the form resubmission problem and allows you to display the latest data without needing to manually refresh the page.

This solution has two advantages, it avoids resubmitting the form, also if you are show updated dat. For example, if the user has added a new row, and you are showing modal data in frontend, it will show the last row added. In traditional method, user has to refresh page to see data ( also refresh resubmits the form).